# Как получить все значения Объекта не перебирая ключи и не ссылаясь на них

Tags: javascript, объекты

Господа, у меня есть объект с разным уровнем вложенности. Как  я могу получить то или иное значение я знаю, ниже есть наглядный пример:

```js
var family = {
  adults: {
    granddad: {
      name: 'Макар',
      age: 76,
      profession: 'Летчик',
      pensioner: 'Да'


    },
    grandmother: {
      name: 'Валентина',
      age: 72,
      profession: 'Преподователь химии',
      pensioner: 'Да'


    },
    father: {
      name: 'Виниамин',
      age: 40,
      profession: 'Художник',
      pensioner: 'Нет'


    },
    mother: {
      name: 'Мария',
      age: 38,
      profession: 'Бухгалтер',
      pensioner: 'Нет'
    }
  },
  сhildren: {
    boys: {
      adults: {
        name: 'Макар',
        age: 18,
        learning: 'Летное училище'
      },
      juvenile: {
        name: 'Алексей',
        age: 17,
        learning: 'Средняя школа №1515'
      }
    },
    girls: {
      adults: {
        name: 'Елизавета',
        age: 20,
        learning: 'Консерватория'
      },
      juvenile: {
        name: 'Диана',
        age: 12,
        learning: 'Средняя школа №1515'
      }
    }
  }
};


var objectValues = ['Макар', 76, 'Летчик', 'Да', 'Валентина', 72, 'Преподователь химии', 'Да', 'Виниамин', 40, , 'Художник', 'Нет', 'Мария', 38, 'Бухгалтер', 'Нет', 'Макар', 18, 'Летное училище', 'Алексей', 17, 'Средняя школа №1515', 'Елизавета', 20, 'Консерватория', 'Диана', 12, 'Средняя школа №1515']

document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += 'Так я получаю все ключи объекта family: <br/>' + '<code>\
 Object.keys(family.adults)<br/>\
 </code>' + Object.keys(family) + ' <hr/>  <br/>';

document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += 'Так я могу получить любое значение: <br/>' + '<code>\
 family.сhildren.boys.adults.name<br/>\
 </code>' + family.сhildren.boys.adults.name + ' <hr/>  <br/>';
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML += '<p>' + objectValues + '</p>'
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 20px;
}

code {
  color: orange;
}

p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Вопрос: как я могу получить все значения данного объекта (пример список красного цвета) со всеми вложенными значениями не ссылаясь на ключи.  Одним словом я хочу получить массив как

> objectValues

не набирая это все в ручную

Comment: у тебя ошибка: _Так я получаю все ключи объекта family_, а получаешь-то ты `family.adults`

Comment: @Grundy, почему ошибка?  Я не имел ввиду и вложенные ключи.. Ну я не правильно выразился...

Comment: _как я могу получить все значения данного объекта_ - напиши функцию, которая будет обходить объект и получать нужные поля

Comment: вот это  примерно, что вы хотите, но с перебором :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217063/recursively-walk-through-an-array-object-with-render-functions-with-javascript#47217861

Comment: @Grundy, функцию то понятно...   А нет какого-нибудь метода на подобии Object.keys(family) , но чтобы в место keys, было бы значение?  что бы именно значение перебирать?

Comment: `Object.values` - но он так же как и keys только у текущего объекта смотрит, не у вложенных. Кроме того, еще плохо поддерживается браузерами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var family = {
  adults: {
    granddad: {
      name: 'Макар',
      age: 76,
      profession: 'Летчик',
      pensioner: 'Да'


    },
    grandmother: {
      name: 'Валентина',
      age: 72,
      profession: 'Преподователь химии',
      pensioner: 'Да'


    },
    father: {
      name: 'Виниамин',
      age: 40,
      profession: 'Художник',
      pensioner: 'Нет'


    },
    mother: {
      name: 'Мария',
      age: 38,
      profession: 'Бухгалтер',
      pensioner: 'Нет'
    }
  },
  сhildren: {
    boys: {
      adults: {
        name: 'Макар',
        age: 18,
        learning: 'Летное училище'
      },
      juvenile: {
        name: 'Алексей',
        age: 17,
        learning: 'Средняя школа №1515'
      }
    },
    girls: {
      adults: {
        name: 'Елизавета',
        age: 20,
        learning: 'Консерватория'
      },
      juvenile: {
        name: 'Диана',
        age: 12,
        learning: 'Средняя школа №1515'
      }
    }
  }
};
Object.values(family.adults).forEach(function(snap) {
 Object.values(snap).forEach(function(snap2) {
  document.write(snap2)
 });
});

Object.values(family.сhildren).forEach(function(snap) {
 Object.values(snap).forEach(function(snap2) {
       Object.values(snap2).forEach(function(snap3) {
             document.write(snap3);
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: user8504903, будь другом подскажи, как получить мне именно массив значений...?  Что бы перебирать их по индексу... Чего то у меня не получается

Comment: Air, Создай пустой массив в самом начале кода. Вот так: **var arr = []**. И вместо **document.write(snap3)** напиши **arr.push(snap3)**

Comment: user8504903, а вот про push забыл...  Не мог понять почему не получается у меня..  Благодарю... Ты умница...)))   Слушай, смени ник, а то не удобно обращаться)))